# Swift: Calling UIButton press from another class

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

I have my `ViewController.class` and a `Menu.class`

In the `Menu.class` I create and setup all the buttons and in the `ViewController.class` I add the Menu to the view. When I run the code everything is shown on the screen but I am not able to press the button.

This is how my ViewController looks like:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let menu = Menu()
        menu.setupView(controller: self, width: 600, height: 120)
        self.view.addSubview(menu)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}
```

And this is my Menu:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Menu: UIView{

    func setupView(controller: ViewController, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat){

        let newGame = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: controller.view.center.x, y: 300, width: width, height: height))
        newGame.center = CGPoint(x: controller.view.center.x, y: 300)
        newGame.setTitle("New Game", for: .normal)
        newGame.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        newGame.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 42)
        newGame.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
        newGame.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Menu.newGame), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.addSubview(newGame)

    }
    func newGame(){
        print("New Game")

    }
}
```

What is my mistake. Do I need to do more initializing so it is able to detect a press?

Comment: Well, I c/c your code & it doesn't even compile for me. First thing I wonder, why Menu doesn't herit directly from UIButton ? Do you plan to have multiple buttons in it ? If yes, how many ? If you want to have a proper code, you should think again about your conception. If you only want to know why it's going bad, it's because your frame are set in an improper way

Comment: I am planning to have 2 buttons and 1 label. I deleted the code for the other 2 things and there is a } missing in Menu. I am sorry.

Comment: the } isn't the only problem. Anyway, If I was you I would delete your Menu and I would create my 2 buttons + label directly in ViewController

Comment: Try changing your addTarget, replacing "self" with "superview".

Comment: Terrible idea dfd. It's adding mess to mess. I don't recommend that.

Comment: @dfd did not work

Comment: As I said, your problem comes from the frame. They are not set in a proper way. That said, the structure doesn't really make sense. There is no point to subclass UIView to put buttons and label in. You can do it directly in viewController

Comment: Ok. When I press New Game it should open a TableView to choose something. Would it make sense to put this on in another class or should it also be in the view controller?

Comment: I think your issue is with the responder chain. You are instantiating a Menu() in your ViewController(). You should let the "menu" be the class that is "tapped", but the view controller should process the tap. Move the newGame() to your view controller and in your addTarget (which also should be in your view controller, reference the viewController. @Eva is correct, your logic isn't really straight forward. Unless you are planning to **reuse** this Menu class in another view controller, it blocks the normal flow of an app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you should do it. Repeat the operation for buttonTwo and label. Setup the view in viewDidLoad() and setup the frames in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

If you subclass any UIView you should setup the frames in layoutSubviews()

If you want to display a tableView when you click on newGame then create a new UIViewController. Add a UITableView in it, the same way you did add Button and Label in ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  let buttonOne = UIButton()
  let buttonTwo = UIButton()
  let label = UILabel()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    buttonOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    buttonOne.setTitle("New Game", for: .normal)
    buttonOne.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 42)
    buttonOne.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    buttonOne.addTarget(self, action: #selector(newGame), for: .touchUpInside)

    view.addSubview(buttonOne)
    view.addSubview(buttonTwo)
    view.addSubview(label)
  }

  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    buttonOne.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: 600, height: 120)
    buttonOne.center.x = self.view.center.x
  }

  func newGame(sender: UIButton?) {
    print("New Game")
  }
}
```